# Use a string (from input) in another class

Tags: java, android, string, variables, static

I have a class in which a string is taken from an input. I want to use the value of the input in a second class.

```
public class Incontrare extends ActionBarActivity {
public static String nome1=null;
public String variabileNome;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incontrare);


    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1Nome);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            alertDia();  //takes the input from variabileNome
            nome1 = variabileNome;
            TextView textv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textv1.setText(nome1);

        }
    });

    public static String getNome1() {return nome1;}
 }
 }
```

And the second class:

```
public class IncontrarePersona1 extends ActionBarActivity {
String nome1=Incontrare.getNome1();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incontrare_persona1);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String toPrint = "There is " + nome1;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toPrint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    });
}
```

I tried the second class also in this way:

```
public class IncontrarePersona1 extends ActionBarActivity {
String nome1=Incontrare.getNome1();
public static String no1;       

 b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
   b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   Incontrare no1= new Incontrare();
   String n1= no1.nome1;
   String toPrint = "There is " + nome1;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toPrint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    });
}
```

Where is the mistake? Why do I get always null?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You try to define a public static field inside a method? This is not possible and should give you errors. Is that just a copy&paste fail? Please correct your question code.

Comment: Interesting if you can grab a value like that, if you can then a problem that might be occuring is if variabileNome is ever not null.  You don't have any code here that shows it isn't always null.

Comment: @Pinkie, you are right, i modified it

Comment: @Ashley the String is modified by the method alertDia() that i didnt write here(the problem is not that one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that when the second `Activity` is brought into focus, the data in the previous Activity is lost.

Create a separate class to hold your static variables that both `Activity`s can access.

Edit:
Another method I use for passing data is the `SharedPreferences` if I'm worried about the entire application losing focus.

Comment: Passing the value through the `intent` is only useful if the first Activity is directly starting the second Activity, which was not stated in the question as part of the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

If you are jumping from activity to another use Bundle.

Bundle example -
Set value

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, IncontrarePersona1.class);
i.putExtra("text", "some text");
startActivity(i);
```

Get Value:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null)
{
 String data= extras.getString("text");
//data is your param
}
```

Otherwise use static class with static variables as Will McG said.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but where should i add the code? If i put it after the declaration of the variables, it gives me errors when i try to open Incontrare.class
Thanks again for the help

Comment: You must set bundle at onCreate method of your first class after initializing a variable that you need to pass in another class.After that to get value from bundle add that lines of code to any method of your second class.
I typed code for setting and getting value just copy paste them.